# JS Map shows only last result

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

can anyone explain me why the map function shows me only the last result and not all?

```
    let err = {
      email: false,
      password: false,
      surname: false,
      lastname: false,
      firma: false,
      url: false
    };

    Object.keys(err).map(el => {
       error.innerText = el;
     });
```

If I write console.log then I get all results...

Comment: Each time through the loop you replace the innerText. At the end it contains the last one you assigned.

Comment: `map()` should only be used when the function returns something and you're using the array of results. If you don't need the results, you should use `forEach()`

Comment: If you want to see all of them, use `+=` to concatenate instead of replacing with `=`.

Comment: `console.log()` doesn't remove previous log messages each time you log something, so of course you see all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time it goes through the loop it changes the error.innerText.
So in the last loop it will assign it to the last key. I would suggest using += instead.

```
Object.keys(err).map(el => {
       error.innerText += el;
     });
```